# How do I yank the text matching a pattern?

Tags: vim

I am trying to perform an action on a searched pattern but I can't figure out how to do that. The goal here is to be able to yank a pattern but so far I can only yank a whole line. Is there a trick that will make this command operate only on a matched pattern?

```
:/pattern.*/v
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do (with sample input/output)?

Comment: Considering the following text: 
_Comments use mini-Markdown formatting
The post author will always be notified of your comment. 
To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name_ 
If I run _:/notify.*/v_ it will yank a whole line with notify pattern. What I would like it to do instead is to yank only a matched pattern, that is: _notify a previous commenter, mention their user name_

Comment: It won't yank anything; I get `E148: Regular expression missing from global` instead.

Comment: Your pattern includes includes regex, not just a string. What if multiple patterns match it and which one will you choose for yanking?

Comment: As far as I know it would match only the first one (missing g flag).

Comment: That's `:/foo/y`, not `:/foo/v`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your Vim is recent enough (7.3.6xx), you can use `gn` in combination with `:normal`:

```
:/foo/normal ygn
```

To yank to a specific register:

```
:/foo/normal "aygn
```

See `:help :normal` and `:help gn`.

Answer (score 0):

To yank all text matched by a pattern, define a function to store a string in a register:

```
fun! Save(s)
    let @a .= a:s . "\n"
endfun
```

Then, clear your register and perform the following substitution:

```
:let @a='' | %s/mypattern/\=Save(submatch(0))/g
```

This will evaluate the expression `Save(submatch(0))` each time the
pattern matches (see `:help :s\=`), and use that for the substitution.
`submatch(0)` returns the matched text (same as `&`), and `Save` will
append this to register `a`. Don't forget to undo afterwards, or include
`return a:s` in the function if you don't want to make destructive edits.

You can then `:new | put a` to see the results. If you want other
information, such as line numbers where the matches occurred, amend the
function:

```
fun! Save(s)
    let @a .= line('.') . ': ' . a:s . "\n"
endfun
```